# How to fetch large files from mongodb without making multiple api calls

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to find a way to fetch a large file without crashing the website.
the large file is an array of objects.
below is the function that I use to fetch the data.

```
async function retrieveData(res, connectionUrl, channelData, start = 1, end = 10) {
  const client = await mongodb.connect(connectionUrl);
  const db = client.db(`${process.env.MODE}_channel_data`);
  const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, { bucketName: 'fs' });

  // Retrieve the stored document
  const downloadStream = bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(channelData.fileName);
  let data = '';
  downloadStream.on('data', chunk => {
    data += chunk;
  });
  downloadStream.on('error', (er) => {
    console.log('EERROR WHILE GETTING DOC', er)
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'An error occurred while retrieving the document'
    });
  });
  await downloadStream.on('end', () => {
    res.status(201).json({
      payload: JSON.parse(data)
    });
    client.close();
  });
}
```

the issue with this method is that it loads the whole file at once, and when is send it to the front end it crashes it.

I have the following work around but I think its terrible:

- system fetches file from MongoDB
- system splits up file and sends him the first 1000 records
- system sends the first 1000 records the user
- if the user wants to see more records:
- system fetches file from MongoDB AGAIN
- system splits up file and sends 1001-2000
- system sends the first 1000 records the user

is there a better way to do this?

is there a cache system or something like that I can use?

thank you!